# Momentum carried by an electromagnetic wave

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum

According to my physics book,

> Whenever a particle absorbs a certain amount of energy from an electromagnetic wave, it also simultaneously absorbs a corresponding momentum in the direction of propagation of the wave

I'm not sure what the term "corresponding" refers to in this sentence.

Comment: This is referring to the Field Momentum; https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html

Comment: Of course it refers to the momentum but the term "corresponding" means that there is a relationship between two things

Comment: The Feynman Lecture link explains this correspondence quite well; the idea of Field Momentum comes from the convenience of being able to treat interactions with fields as continuous collisions that must obey the conservation of momentum, much like how we treat elastic collisions. The correspondence is that both of these quantities of a field are conserved. These two quantities can be seen as invariant quantities of the EM field Tensor for a more unified view of whats happening, but that is not necessary to understand the correspondence. Im sure the link should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, from relativity we learn that $m^2 c^2 = E^2/c^2 - p^2$. If you substitute in $p=0$ you get Einstein’s famous $E=mc^2$. Since light is massless you can instead substitute in $m=0$ and get $E=pc$. So for a massless thing like light there is a definite corresponding amount of momentum associated with any given amount of energy.

Comment: Okay, but "corresponding" indicates a relationship between two things. In my case the relationship exists between the momentum and ... ?

Comment: @Angelo Giannuzzi Energy. $E=pc$ means there is a relationship between energy and momentum